# How to find rank(W) and nullity(W) of an nxn matrix $W = (w_{ij})$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $n \le 2$, and consider the nxn matrix $W = (w_{ij})$, where $w_{ij} = 1$ for all $1 \le i,j \le n$.

I've tried writing the given conditions in English but so far, I couldn't find any piece of information that can aid me in finding rank(W) and nullity(W). I also know the definition of i,j-cofactor and its relation in finding the determinant in an mxn matrix, but how do I link these theories to the exercise?

Comment: If all the entries on the matrix are ones, then its rank is 1, it follows that nullity is n-1, no?

Comment: I guess you can say that I got confused between $w_{ij}$ and $(w_{ij})$, I can see where you get the answers from now. Much thanks!